# Why I cant Check a Single Radio Button In Android List View

Tags: java, android, listview

I have 2 textviews and 4 radiobutton in my android listview.I am able to add 10 items in listview using the following code.

```
productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("id", id);
map.put("name", name);
map.put("a",ans1);
map.put("b",ans2);
map.put("c",ans3);
map.put("d",ans4);

productsList.add(map);      
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Test.this, productsList, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"pid", "name","a","b","c","d"},
                                    new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.rb1, R.id.rb2, R.id.rb3, R.id.rb4});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

When i click on radiobutton on second child,It also selects radio button of 7th child.When i click 3rd child it automatically selects 9th child.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/rg"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

        >
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rb1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rb2"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rb3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rb4"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

How i can fix this problem.

Comment: post code of SimpleAdapter also.

Comment: import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) for `SimpleAdapter` indicates that for a view that implements `Checkable`, the expected bind value is a boolean.  Your list items contain `RadioButtons`. `RadioButton` extends `CompoundButton`, which implements `Checkable`.  So you need to bind a boolean value to the `RadioButton`s instead of a `String` value.  You can do this by defining your HashMap like this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

and then storing boolean values in the map for the `RadioButtons` and `String` values for "name" and "pid".